# Continous Python console pop up after installing Pycharm 4.0.1

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I recently updated to Pycharm 4 and all of a sudden, am gettin these crazy console pop ups whenever I launch Pycharm,run an app,or even press any button that fires any sort of event in the editor.

[image]

I have unchecked the `Use IPython if available` option in both the `settings` and in the `default settings` menus, restarted Pycharm with no luck. How do i solve this problem? Can i uninstall IPython?

Comment: You didn't write when these windows pop up.

Comment: I have updated the question to show this.